# Problem with deploying my first streamlit app on heroku

Tags: heroku, streamlit

I am trying to deploy my first streamlit app on heroku and I’m getting the following Log:

```
2020-06-27T18:17:07.448037+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc=“No web processes running” method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mushrooms-classification.herokuapp.com request_id=b238d448-c508-48fa-af72-a1b57bfa7e2c fwd=“1.38.55.176” dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Can someone explain to me what could be the reason?

My Procfile contains

```
web: sh setup.sh && streamlit run app.py
```

My setup.sh file contains

```
mkdir -p ~/.streamlit/

echo "\
[server]\n\
port = $PORT\n\
enableCORS = false\n\
headless = true\n\
\n\
" > ~/.streamlit/config.toml
```

The app is working fine on my local system.

My git repository is [this](https://github.com/ravi-kr/project-1-mushrooms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood the problem I was facing. While uploading my initial files on github, github changed the name of requirements.txt to requirements.txt.txt. I changed the name manually to requirements.txt on github and tried to deploy on Heroku. I think Heroku was still reading the name as requirements.txt.txt and the app was not getting deployed. So, I deleted the requirements.txt file on github and manually created another requirements.txt file on github itself. After that, I tried to deploy the app on Heroku, and it was successfully deployed.